# Raphael Scope Drag n drop multiple paper instances

Tags: javascript, scope, raphael

I have two Raphael paper instances. In both I want to drag and drop an element (circle). It is important for me to assign both these circles the same id. I expected no problem, as both are in different paper instances and therefore in different scope. What happens is, that somehow both elements react, when I have clicked both elements at least once. If I however give these elements different IDs everything works fine (each element only calls its "start", "drag" and "up" function if draged around).
Is this intended behaviour of Raphael and do I have to assign different IDs to the elements in the different paper instances? Hopefully not and you can point me to the right direction :-)
Thanks a lot for your Help in advance, Here comes the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>DragNDrop</title>   
        <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Paper1</h1>
    <div id="divPaper1" style ="height: 150px; width: 300px; border:thin solid red"></div>
    <h1>Paper2</h1>
    <div id="divPaper2" style ="height: 150px; width: 300px; border:thin solid red"></div>
    <script>
        start1 = function () {
            console.log("start1");
        }
        drag1 = function () {
            console.log("move1");
        }
        up1 = function () {
            console.log("up1");
        }
        start2 = function () {
            console.log("start2");
        }
        drag2 = function () {
            console.log("move2");
        }
        up2 = function () {
            console.log("up2");
        }
        var paper1 = Raphael("divPaper1", "100%", "100%");
        var circle1 = paper1.circle(40, 40, 30);
        circle1.attr("fill", "yellow");
        circle1.id = "circle";        //both circles get the same id
        circle1.drag(drag1, start1, up1);
        paper2 = Raphael("divPaper2", "100%", "100%");
        var circle2 = paper2.circle(40, 40, 30);
        circle2.attr("fill", "red");
        circle2.id = "circle";        //both circles get the same id
        circle2.drag(drag2, start2, up2);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: No ideas? One additional information: I use Raphael 2.1.2.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, all must be unique within a document, which isn't the case here. So I think you will need to find a workaround. If you say whats limiting you to keeping them the same, someone may be able to figure a workaround though.

Comment: @Ian, THX for your answer. I hoped to be able to avoid this workaround because I was quite sure that each paper has its own scope. As it seems, that's not the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround, to check what the parent of the element is that took the event. I should say that really you don't want two unique elements, and you should try and design a way to avoid this. That being said, this type of solution could give you an idea for a workaround....

So we would just have one event handle for start which checks itself...

```
   start = function () {
        if( this.paper.canvas.parentElement.id == 'divPaper1' ) {
            console.log( 'from divpaper1');
        } else {
            console.log( 'from divpaper2');
        };
    }
```

I've added it to a fiddle here, which just shows the start handler, not the drag/mouseup http://jsfiddle.net/kTYAs/. This type of solution could be more useful in that you only need one function each to implement the start,move,up